# unsigned long , unsigned char in Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am changing my Objective C project to Swift project. In objective C I used unsigned long, Unsigned char.

```
const char * bytesIn = [self bytes];
unsigned long bytesLength = range.location + range.length;
unsigned long   bytesOffset = range.location;
NSMutableData * dataOut = [NSMutableData data];

BOOL currIsEOF = NO;
unsigned char currChar;         /* current character */
unsigned char charBuf[MAX_READ];    /* buffer of already read characters */
int count;                       /* number of characters in a run */

/* prime the read loop */
currChar = bytesIn[bytesOffset];
bytesOffset = bytesOffset + skip;
count = 0;
```

The above is the code. Can Anybody help to change this to a Swift one. In Swift to my understanding there is no **const char**

Comment: `const char *` maps to Swift as `UnsafeRawPointer`. However, porting ObjC code by substituting it for Swift line-by-line very rarely yields good Swift code. There's almost always a better/clearer/simpler way to do it Swift. So I recommend you post your main problem as a new question, rather than trying to translate it over line by line.

Comment: I didn't down vote BTW. Though I've seen enough questions like this that it's time I made a flowchart to better explain what I'm saying. Check out https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cg2IzoybZSIyQ1wx0mZDC2m66lcLZkPN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: BTW - your Objective-C code is using many incorrect types. `NSData bytes` is `void *`, not `char *`. `NSRange` uses `NSUInteger`, not `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet looks like part of a larger function that is extracting some bytes out of an `NSData` object. Swift provides [`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data) which bridges to `NSData` and provides a whole slew of functions to manipulate byte buffers Swift collections. You should look at the larger function your snippet is from and recast the algorithm using the functions provided by `Data`.

BTW Swift provides unsigned types, for some reason it views them as [Special-Use Numeric Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/special-use_numeric_types) and also provides type aliases named after C types, see [C Interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/c_interoperability). So if you have algorithms which use unsigned types and/or Objective-C code for them, you can write/translate them into Swift – indeed it seems the result will be "special" to Swift folk when of course unsigned numbers are really [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) ;-)